# What does this comparison mean?

Tags: python

I just read the following line in a script:

```
fn = (len(sys.argv) > 2 and [sys.argv[2]] or ['test_out.jpg'])[0]
```

I don't really get what's going on here. So there is a comparison of the number of arguments with 2 and then an or statement. What is the author doing with this and is it a good coding style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I find it bad coding style since it's not that obvious what is happening (hence, your question).

What it is doing:

1. See if `sys.argv` has more than 2 items
2. If it has more than 2 items, return `[sys.argv[2]]`
3. Otherwise, return `['test_out.jpg']`
4. From the previous returned item (which is always a list), return item 0.

A simpler version would be:

```
fn = sys.argv[2:] and sys.argv[2] or 'test_out.jpg'
```

A more readable version:

```
fn = sys.argv[2] if sys.argv[2:] else 'test_out.jpg'
```

Comment: thanks - didn't know `sys.argv[2:]` was functionally equivalent to `len(sys.argv)>2`...

Answer (score 5):

```
fn = (len(sys.argv) > 2 and [sys.argv[2]] or ['test_out.jpg'])[0]
```

is like:

```
fn = ([sys.argv[2]] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else ['test_out.jpg'])[0]
```

In plain statements:

```
if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    fn = [sys.argv[2]][0]
else:
    fn = ['test_out.jpg'][0]
```

As you can see `[...][0]` is somewhat redundant. So original statement could be replacecd as follow:

```
fn = len(sys.argv) > 2 and sys.argv[2] or 'test_out.jpg'
```

**UPDATE** Above code will not work if `sys.argv[2]` is empty string. That's why original code use `[...][0]` form. So use following form if possible:

```
fn = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else 'test_out.jpg'
```

Comment: Probably a remnant of pre-2.5 era, before PEP308 was introduced.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I'm not a native english speaker so I have trouble finding this short code in the documentation. How is it called?

Comment: @JasonTS It is similar to a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)

Comment: The `[...][0]` is probably meant to handle the case that `sys.argv[2]` is the empty string correctly (which seems pointless anyway).

Answer (score 0):

`and` and `or` in python act like short-circuits in certain cases.

In a expression `x and y`, if x evaluates to `False`, then there is no need to even look at y since the result will be false.  Say, you want to get `sys.argv[2]`, but only in the case when there are enough arguments.  Then you could do:

len(sys.argv) > 2 and [sys.argv[2]]

So, if `sys.argv` has length 2 or less, then `len(sys.argv) > 2` will evaluate to false and it will not evaluate `sys.argv[2]` (and hence not run into an `IndexError`).

Similarly, in an expression `x or y`, only when `x` evaluates to `False` will `y` be evaluated.  Hence, if the number of arguments is less than or equal to 2, then `fn` will take the value `['test_out.jpg']`.

Finally, the brackets are for then getting the zeroth index using the final `[0]` in the expression.

In summary: if the number of arguments is 2 or more, then assign `fn` to `sys.argv[2]`, else assign `fn` to `'test.out.jpg'`.